# Cannot import assertThat method junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, hamcrest, junit5

I am using hamcrest and junit to perform the tests, I need to compare 2 maps that have the same items but in different order, so assertEquals does not work for me.
I have already seen the answers that have been put to that, but I have not been able to import the required methods.

I am importing in the following way

```
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
```

and then I try the next thing I've seen in the answers

```
assertThat(expectedMap, containsInAnyOrder(receivedMap));
```

but does not recognize the method assertThat, the IDE shows me a warning that asks me to create the method

[image: IntelliJ error tooltip: "assertThat(java.util.Map,org.hamcrest.Matcher>>)"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map` does not implement `Iterable`. Thus, the method signature does not match with the inferred argument types `Map<?>` and `Matcher<Iterable<?>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the wrong `assertThat` method, what you want is the one from [hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/MatcherAssert.html#assertThat(T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)) :

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
```

Comment: I changed it, but it still does not work, the warning continues